# Highcharts export server use not correct font letter

Tags: highcharts, fonts

I have some misunderstanding with the highcharts export server and font.
I install the next font Frutiger-Light on the 'window 10' machine and in the config of legend I wrote the fond name

```
 "legend": {
    "layout": "horizontal",
    "align": "center",
    "verticalAlign": "bottom",
    "floating": false,
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0,
    "itemDistance": 10,
    "itemStyle": {
        "color": "#c00",
        "fontFamily": "Frutiger-Light (TrueType)",
        "fontSize": "30px",
        "fontWeight": "100",
        "lineHeight": "16px"
    }
```

In the preview of the font, I saw
[image]

but when exported this config by server I saw the next

[image]

my legend has the wrong letter a, In Microsoft office the letter is correct (without tail), after highcharts server with, Why? I can't understand

(I try other fonts from the 'Frutiger' family and I have the same problem)

Comment: This means that other types of custom fonts export correctly, the problem only arises with 'Frutiger' fonts? Have you tested it?

Comment: yes, with 'Arial' it works, but possibly, it's happened because I downloaded free font for tests, not a licensed font(I downloaded about 5 different types of 'Frutiger' from different free sources). Can be it the reason? Sorry for the longer answer

Comment: Yes, it is also possible that some fonts are simply not supported since the more universal ones work fine. It would also be worth checking.

Comment: Sorry for the long answer, I have received a licensed font of Frutiger and the font have the same problems, some letters doesn't correct